# can not import tensorflow correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can not import tensorflow correctly,
but one month ago it worked!

I have no idea what happened.

My system info:

> window 7 Professional 64bit

```
print (sys.version)
```

> 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Sep 19 2017, 08:03:39) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

```
sys.version_info
```

> sys.version_info(major=3, minor=6, micro=2, releaselevel='final',
>   serial=0)

```
!pip show tensorflow
```

> Name: tensorflow Version: 1.3.0

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line
>   24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py",
>   line 77, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator_lib as estimator
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator_lib.py",
>   line 22, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.estimator.canned.dnn import DNNClassifier
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\canned\dnn.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.estimator import estimator
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py",
>   line 40, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.ops import metrics as metrics_lib
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\metrics.py",
>   line 51, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.ops.metrics_impl import *
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\metrics_impl.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.ops import nn
>
> File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn.py",
>   line 146, in 
>       [_sys.modules[**name**], _ctc_ops, _nn_ops, _nn_grad])
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\all_util.py",
>   line 103, in remove_undocumented
>       should_have = make_all(module_name, doc_string_modules)
>
> File
>   "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\all_util.py",
>   line 55, in make_all
>       for m in _reference_pattern.finditer(doc_module.**doc**)
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: What version of python are you using? I've not used Tensorflow but it's common to run into those sorts of errors between py2 and py3 (e.g. running a py2 app in py3)

Comment: i use python 3.6.2

Comment: What has changed since your last month in your code or your environment? Did you made any changes?

Comment: I use the same computer, and don't install any software, but i have install keras today, it also can't works.

Comment: Hey, i solve this problem by reinstall tensorflow, thanks for every comment.